# Best practices in Working with strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am currently making a small C++ tool , and I am kind of shocked on the way of How to deal with strings in C++. This is the first time i need to deal with C++ , I have pretty much experience with Managed languages with strong types like Java , C# but I am getting mad with C++ strings.

Are there any best practices to work with strings in C++ ?

A lot of WIN API functions dealing with different type of "strings"

tchar , char* , LPWSTR , LPCSTR ... etc.
and converting each type to other is taking a lot of time for me to implement.

Please suggest your way of dealing with strings when converting one type to another.
Maybe there is some library to use ?

Comment: Use std::string and std::wstring.

Comment: What @Robinson said. tchar, char * ,LPWSTR, LPCSTR are not actual strings, but pointers to arrays of chars.

Comment: tchar  is not a string. it's single char. just saying...

Comment: This question is very unfocused. You're not saying what *exactly* it is you need to do. You just talk about doing string conversions without saying exactly which formats you convert from/to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer? Use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) or `std::wstring` wherever you can is my advice.

```
std::string strBuffer = "test";
strBuffer += " ... test";
std::string::size_type nStringSize = strBuffer.size();
const char* pszString = strBuffer.c_str();    // pszString contains 
                                              // pointer to memory held 
                                              // by STL string and can be 
                                              // passed into API calls
```

You can easily obtain a "c style" string (i.e. a pointer to a null terminate char array `char*` by `.c_str()` which you can pass into most WinAPI functions as is.

Most of the other types you mention (`tchar`, `LPWSTR`, `LPCSTR` etc) are typedefs to C style arrays (or pointers to C style arrays, or char types) for supporting unicode over multibyte character sets.

Comment: `char* pszString = strBuffer.c_str();` - invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’

Comment: @the_mandrill most of the time this will suffice. I've not seen many (any?) API calls that modify the string that is passed in. Of course I'm sure I've not come across every API call in Windows yet ;-)

Comment: @awoodland: that and the weird hungarian notation... oh well.

Comment: @MatthieuM why weird Hungarian? `p`ointer to a `s`tring `z`ero (or null) terminated. Meh :-P

Comment: @Konrad: because it's the dreaded (and useless) Systems Hungarian notation, while Charles Simonyi always intended what is now called the Applications Hungarian notation. *Duplicating* the type system information is useless and harmful: it does not bring any additional value, but still complicates the name of the variable *and* induces the risk that a refactoring will change either type or name without changing the other, leaving the code in an unwieldy state (which is a typical issue with duplication btw).

Comment: @Konrad, there are plenty WinAPI functions that *can* modify the string if asked to.  DrawText is one example.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As Robinson said, if you've got used to managed languages your most convenient way will be with STDL strings. w... is wide (used for example for Unicode), without w will be 8 bit.

The most "traditional" C++ (or better, C) strings are `char*` that is a simple pointer to a character series in the memory, followed by null byte `\0`. It's not a class just the pure data thus you don't have a-prior info for example about its length: every time you need the length you have to count it yourself by iterating through the chars until you find the `\0`. Exactly this is that the `strlen` function does. There are a lot of other helper functions for the traditional str... including cropping, copying, concatenating etc. them but they are not "safe" in the sense that one can easily overwrite some data behind the string if the original memory allocated memory was not enough. This was the exploited by most of viruses in the 90s.

So if you want safe and convenient solution, go for standard template library strings.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected this inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggest your way of dealing with strings when converting one type to another. Maybe there is some library to use ?

Normally (99% cases) in c++ you should use `std::string` (or `std::wstring`).

If you fall into 1%, when you have to deal with c strings, you have to be extra careful. Then you need to deal with pointers to char arrays and tchar , char* , LPWSTR , LPCSTR types